# Access denied CORs request in IE10+ in angularjs with required Cross Origin Resource Sharing error (info?)

Tags: angularjs, xmlhttprequest, cors

I thought the days of cross browser support were a thing of the past with the various libraries out there insulating from some of the nuance and the purported standardisation of web browsers but....

I am trying to perform a $http get request using angularjs (v1.2.27) thus:

```
       $http({
            url: vm.hostName + '/pdf/' + id,
            method : 'GET',
            responseType : 'arraybuffer',
            cache : false})
            .success(function (response) {

                var file = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/pdf' });

                var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                console.log(fileURL);
                console.log(response.data);
                window.open(fileURL);
      });
```

which works swimmingly on Chrome, FF and Safari (Mac and Win 7, 8 so far), but not on IE10+, I get this:

> SEC7118: XMLHttpRequest for https://[api.domain.com]/pdf/55abc12345613af7946e required Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).
>   Error: Access is denied.
>   at Anonymous function (https://[domain.com]/site/scripts/scripts.js:289:6)
>      at Anonymous function (https://[domain.com]/public/assets/js/angular/angular.js:7736:11)
>      at wrappedCallback (https://[domain.com]/public/assets/js/angular/angular.js:11106:15)
>      at wrappedCallback (https://[domain.com]/public/assets/js/angular/angular.js:11106:15)
>      at Anonymous function (https://[domain.com]/public/assets/js/angular/angular.js:11192:11)
>      at Scope.prototype.$eval (https://[domain.com]/public/assets/js/angular/angular.js:12181:9)
>      at Scope.prototype.$digest (https://[domain.com]/public/assets/js/angular/angular.js:12010:15)
>      at Scope.prototype.$apply (https://[domain.com]/public/assets/js/angular/angular.js:12285:13)
>      at done (https://[domain.com]/public/assets/js/angular/angular.js:7994:34)
>      at completeRequest (https://[domain.com]/public/assets/js/angular/angular.js:8196

The response headers returned by the api server are

```
Key Value
Response    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server  nginx/1.8.0
Date    Tue, 25 Aug 2015 13:40:45 GMT
Content-Type    application/pdf
Content-Length  86057
Connection  keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Methods    GET, PUT, POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers    Origin, Content-Type, Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
Content-Transfer-Encoding   binary
```

and if I look at the response body (in developer tools) I get a message that it can't be rendered (not unreasonably as it is a pdf), but a link to save the content is provided which when saved and opened shows the correct pdf.

The network response appears to show that the content is downloaded given the content-length.

I've looked at a number of CORs related posts but to no avail. The closest one [SEC7118: XMLHttpRequest for /socket.io/1/?t=1370206038749 required Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16887567/sec7118-xmlhttprequest-for-socket-io-1-t-1370206038749-required-cross-origin) doesn't help.
The Microsoft blog http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/02/09/cors-for-xhr-in-ie10.aspx doesn't give any more clues either (I'm guessing it may have something to do with the 'arraybuffer' and binary data, but am now at a dead end and looking for further inspiration.

Anyone suggest anything else? 
ps. I am in control of the server api and it is being services by vert.x (v2.5) as a Java REST service.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The resolution posted [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27463901/setting-window-location-or-window-open-in-angularjs-gives-access-is-denied-in) sorted the problem. 
The issues wasn't with the response back from the server, the issue was with the opening of the url created by

```
var file = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/pdf' });
var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
```

The IE doesn't support window.open of the generated blob:xxx-yyy url.
See link answer for required javascript for displaying blobs in IE10+ (which was what I wanted).